# Model JPA One-To-Many without an actual Parent Entity

Tags: java, jpa, ehcache

I have a problem where I have a number of tables which have a `PersonID` (`PID`) column.

I want to hang these entities off a parent entity using the `PID` as a foreign key using `JPA` one to many collections, and use EhCache, for caching purposes.

It sounds simple enough, the trouble is that I  do not have a parent entity! The reason I do not have a parent is that we are writing a reporting application, and the `PID` is what we are using to write notes against.

I don't really want to create a new table, and just store a `PID` for the purpose of `JPA` and EhCache configuration.

I was wondering if I could mimic an entity or something like that but for all the searching I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: Can you add some examples of kind of queries you want to run?

Comment: I would like to be able to have a set of notes and events associated with each PID.

Comment: So, in one query, get an object that contains references to all the Note entities and Event entities that share the PID?

Comment: Precisely. My problem is that I do not have that base object

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'virtual' entity or anything like that, so you can't do what you're looking for in Hibernate alone.

I would suggest though simply doing it in code, in an abstraction layer (a DAO for the `Person` class, basically) on top of two queries, something like:

```
private static Person lookupPerson(Session s, int pid) {
    List<Note> notes = s.createCriteria(Note.class).add(Restrictions.eq("pid", pid)).list();
    List<Event> events = s.createCriteria(Event.class).add(Restrictions.eq("pid", pid)).list();

    Person p = new Person(notes, events);
    return p;
}

private static Person savePerson(Session s, Person p) {
    for (Note note : p.getNotes()) {
        s.saveOrUpdate(note);
    } 

    for (Event event : p.getEvents()) {
        s.saveOrUpdate(event);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you  Sharakan,
I thought about that approach, but it doesn't help me with caching or the basic ability to add to collections and get the data persisted.
Simon

Comment: For persisting data, sure it can.  Just extend the idea of the DAO as an adapter to multiple queries.  See my updated code for `savePerson`.  For ehcache, you're going to have to be more specific.  What is it you want to do with caching?

Comment: In a multi user environment this might not work too well. If two users were to update two different notes for same person in the same period they would overwrite one another. With Hibernate/Ehcache managing collections this wouldn't be an issue. I've a feeling creating a base entity for the PID might be the simplest solution.

Comment: I absolutely agree that creating a base entity is the simplest solution.  Your point about overwriting isn't valid though.  If two users updated different notes, they would not be overwritten, Hibernate won't save the non-dirty versions.  And if they change the same notes, optimistic versioning will throw an exception.